# SQL query to find the top rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I am trying to get the top 5 salaries.

I have salaries like

```
5000
5000
4500
4500
3000
2000 
1000
500
400
```

and I'd like to get

```
5000
5000
4500
4500
3000
2000
1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the top 5 distinct salaries (no matter how many times the same amount might show up), you need to use the `DENSE_RANK()` ranking function and a CTE to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @salaries TABLE (salary DECIMAL(18,4))

INSERT INTO @salaries VALUES(5000)
INSERT INTO @salaries VALUES(5000)
INSERT INTO @salaries VALUES(4500)
INSERT INTO @salaries VALUES(4500)
INSERT INTO @salaries VALUES(3000)
INSERT INTO @salaries VALUES(2000)
INSERT INTO @salaries VALUES(1000)
INSERT INTO @salaries VALUES(500)
INSERT INTO @salaries VALUES(400)

;WITH SalariesRanked AS
(
    SELECT 
        Salary, 
        SalaryNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC)
    FROM    
        @salaries
)
SELECT salary
FROM SalariesRanked 
WHERE SalaryNumber <= 5
```

This results in an output like this:

```
salary
5000.0000
5000.0000
4500.0000
4500.0000
3000.0000
2000.0000
1000.0000
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 5 salary FROM your_table
ORDER BY salary DESC
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to get the top 5 (distinct) salary amounts - no matter how many times each salary amount shows up. At least that's what his edit in the middle some time seemed to indicate....

Comment: The very first posting: yes. But the OP changed his question in edit #4 to indicate the current situation.

Comment: @marc_s: now I see, but I answered right after OP posted his question... and yes, now the question is different and my answer does not address his problem... so should I delete it in your opinion?

Comment: Leave it - it does address the question: *how to get the top 5 salaries* - the OP changed his mind in the middle of the game.....

Answer (score 1):

```
select salary
from
  (
    select salary,
           dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) as rn
    from YourTable
  ) as T
where rn <= 5
```

Try on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66655)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using [TOP (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5 Salary
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY Salary
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

---

You need to group the query to avoid the duplicated salaries.